# Cannot import module from another module, but can so from a third module (all in different packages)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

my setup:

```
project
    extract (package)
    -> extract_step.py 

    text (package)
    -> paragraph.py

    util (package)
    -> paths.py
```

All three packages have empty `__init__.py` in them. PyDev also shows the packages with the package icon if that matters.
In extract_step.py I can import like so:

```
from text.paragraph import Paragraph
```

And instantiate Paragraph objects and use them.

In paths.py I try to import the exact same way, but I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'text.paragraph'; 'text' is not a package
```

I am using Eclipse and PyDev 5.3. Python 3.5.2.
My PYTHONPATH in Eclipse has only:

```
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}
```

I can run the extract_step.py without issues, but I can not run paths.py without getting the error message (even if the import is the only line in paths.py). What can I do to fix this and why does this happen?

EDIT:
I have tried making a new package, with a new module test.py. I can import in that! I have also tried making a new module in the util package, and it does not work in that either.

Comment: Add `__init__.py` to ALL the directories i.e. __extract__, __text__ and __util__.

Comment: All three of them have it, it is empty in all of them.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read that part of your question. Can you delete all the `pyc` files and run it again?

Comment: I deleted all of them, same problem still. I also restarted Eclipse after deleting them just in case this matters.

Comment: Interestingly I replicated the same directory structure but using Python 2.7 but I do get an error when I run `python extract/extract_step.py`

Comment: I have tried making a new package, with a new module test.py. I can import in that! I have also tried making a new module in the util package, and it does not work in that either.

Comment: So I think I know what's happening. When IDE's are used to run a python module like `extract_step.py` it runs with the `-m` option like `python -m extract.extract_step`. Can you tell me if you were to run the program from the command line, what command would you use?

Comment: `python paths.py` - which produces the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127208/discussion-between-kiran-koduru-and-lomtrur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (to fix it):

I deleted the `util` package.
I re-created the package and the `paths.py`.
It now works.
This answers the "How do I fix this" part of my question, but not the WHY.

If anyone knows why this happened I will accept their answer, but for now, if anyone runs into the same problem, this is how I fixed it.

Comment: My guess is you were using Python 2.7 and had by accident `text.py`  inside util which was being gotten as a relative import (only in Python 3 all imports are absolute, although you can put a `from __future__ import absolute` in the top of your module to force imports to be absolute on Python 2.7 too).